# Fullpage.js -- creating parallal sections/slides?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I'm having issues figuring out how Fullpage.js does this -- I'll just use a picture to explain what I'm trying to go for. Does anyone know how this is possible? I found a great example of what I'm looking for -- here: http://www.sony-asia.com/microsite/mdr-10/#homePage-- yet the code of this website is beyond me and I'm having troubles trying to replicate it.

Illustration of what I'm trying to make

[image: Illustration of what I'm trying to make]